# how can i call function when data changed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, observers

I have tableview in main.swift
and if

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

is called(in appdelegate) my db get new data.

but my view isn't change beacause i didn't call `tableview.reloadData`

so my question is how can i call `tableview.reloadData` after

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

called.
(I tried Main().myreload (//custom function) but it show fatal error..)

Comment: You can use `NSNotificationCenter`, check this article about how to use it:
http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/notifications-and-userinfo-with-swift-3-0/

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed hey... really thanks... that is best answer

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy it helped you with the help of others ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems strange that you'd get an `application(_:open:options:)` call when your database has been reloaded. That function will be called when an external app tells your app to open a URL.

If that's really true, you need a way to get a message from your app delegate to whoever cares. I would suggest defining and using a `NotificationCenter` message. Have the view controller that contains the table view call `addObserver(forName:object:queue:using:)` (or `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`, but the first flavor is more Swift-like.)

Then in your `application(_:open:options:)` method, use `post(name:object:userInfo:) or one of it's variants to broadcast a notification when the URL open method is called.

(In general the app delegate should have as little app-specific business logic in it as possible. By using `NotificationCenter` you can write your app delegate so it doesn't know or care which view controller needs to be notified about the incoming Open URL command.)

Comment: Thanks for answer my question. When application(_:open:options:) called database has been reloaded because i coding there. ha ha I think i'm not good at english so you misunderstand my question.:)

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to reload table from

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
```

First of all, I believe that your data from DB is not loaded in this method, but in some other part of the code where you pull data from the server or even from a local DB In both cases, you could use a completion handler where you reload table when you finish pulling data from the DB.

Also, if you want to reload table from AppDelegate, you should have a reference to a UITableView in AppDelegate, which is not good practice. You maybe could use notifications or delegate methods, but both of them aren't good practice for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are paying attention to the wrong delegate method. Sure, within the App lifecycle you'll get the load URL event, but this is a view issue. When your App is re-opened with the relevant view on screen, you'll *also* get a `viewWillAppear()` callback, which you can implement. This has the advantage of covering more situations.

Comment: thank for comment and that is very useful information for me.
you mean viewWillAppear() is fired after get load URL event?